# Antonym of approaching?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, verbs

Thesaurus.com offers these antonyms to 'approach':

> Antonyms for approach
>
> ```
> departure
> exit
>
> distancing
> leaving
> ```

The "departure" "exit" and "leaving" don't really match, as they'd work with 'intercept' or 'arrive', distance zero. "Distancing" is defined as

> make (someone or something) far off or remote in position or nature.
>
> *"her mother wished to distance her from the rough village children"*

This is about making *the target* more distant from *the subject*, not making *the subject* more distant from *the target* - you won't say *the train is distancing the station*.

Is there a clear expression that's antonymous to "approaching"?

The specific context where I want to use this expression is in orbital mechanics; a body in elliptical orbit moving past apoapsis enters the approaching half of the orbit, then it passes the periapsis (nearest point) and enters *???* half of the orbit...?

Comment: With trains, 'the train now approaching ...' has the counterpart 'the train now departing from ...'. Transitive 'depart' is archaic.  With your other example, 'get [well] away from' would be many people's choice; some might use 'distance herself from'.

Comment: receding.......

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: The case with trains isn't so clear-cut, because the train is first announced a while before it enters the station (is approaching) and then again when it's about to depart. There is no announcement made when it's already a kilometer away and going towards the next destination.

Comment: What kind of word are you looking for? Something technical in use by astronomers, or a common word that would be readily understood by non-scientists? Would an apt but very rare or obsolete word work?

Comment: @1006a: technical is okay, common but accurate would be better; something that is out of contemporary use - not so much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Things recede into the distance as they move away from some other position. Oxford Dictionaries Online provides example sentences for [*recede*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/recede) that seem to meet your sense:

> - And it is the galaxies, not individual stars, that are receding from one another, being carried farther apart as the space in which they are embedded expands.
> - Thus the moon is slowly receding from Earth at about 4 cm per year, and the rate would have been greater in the past.
> - Pluto is now rapidly receding from the sun, and some astronomers have argued that if a spacecraft isn't launched within the next few years, the planet will be completely frozen over by the time a probe arrives.

In *Robotic Exploration of the Solar System: Part 3: Wows and Woes, 1997–2003*, authors Paolo Ulivi and David Harland use this verb in the context of apoapsis as you would:

> As Cassini receded to apoapsis it took some long-range pictures of Iapetus.

So that would appear to fit your exact use here.

Comment: The train now receding from Platform 4 is ...? This works in _some_ situations. I wouldn't have said very many.

Answer (score 1):

A few verbs include the preposition "away" might be suited (implying the movement): keep away, draw away, pull away, move away.

In your example: "her mother wished to **keep away / move away** her from the rough village children".

If you want to keep the distance word, another possibility would be to write:
"her mother wished to put some distance between herself and the rough village children".

Comment: I've never seen 'put some distance with'. Have you a reference or acceptable example? Is it an Americanism?

Comment: I believe, I should have written distance between... I edited my answer.
http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/put-some-distance-between

Another example : He wants to put distance between himself and his former boss. from https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/distance

Answer (score -1):

My understanding is the antonym of "to approach" is "to pass". The reason is given below using reference to the cognitive linguistic notion of deixis. Deixis is the sense of spatial manifestation of a meaning - the origio is the point at which the meaning can be determined to originate and/or be perceived to come into being - similar to the point of view.

The etymology of the transitive and intransitive verb implies to come or to go near: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/approach. "To approach" also implies not yet having arrived or joined, making an overture to but not being conclusive.

The conceptual metaphorical basis of the verb "to approach" from the etymology then is spatial as in "near". The antonym would then have to be based on the spatial locator of "far". As to approach implies not actually having arrived, then the antonym would also need to imply not gone completely:  within the field of influence, but not controlled (which seems to rule out "recede").

It can also be configured in the spatial sense of distance as a metaphorical representation of time e.g. "approaching noon". This last example is interesting because it implies a deictic angle of perception which passes through the origio: approaching therefore allows for the implication of not actually arriving, but passing through, passing by, turning away, stopping, or withdrawing - there is no implication of closure available in the meaning of "to approach" therefore perhaps there is no possibility for a direct antonym that means the opposite in only one plane of movement. The approach does not have to end with a reversal, it can end with other outcomes.

We can still try for a direct antonym, however: we can logically propose that the antonym should imply far away, but never completely severing the connection and in that way rule out a number of suggested options. The verb implies near but without making a connection.  "To depart", therefore, is not right as it implies an actual point of separation. In terms of the corporeal aspect, "to depart" implies a sense of movement of one part of a body from one place to somewhere else, until it is actually gone (one can "approach" death, but one is still alive, however the "dearly departed" have already gone") i.e. departure means separation and leaving. The opposite of departure in this sense would be "to arrive" when the deictic origio will be fused into one body.

"To approach" implies an infinitive sense of mantaining two origios: two discrete bodies that do not fuse into one but can. In the example of the aeroplane, the pilot approaches or makes her "approach to land" an aeroplane, but verb equivalent to depart is "to land" not "to approach".

The answer by tchrist above is not correct. "Recede" means in the first instance to move from an existing position. This is not the antonym of approach, because approach has neither a fixed or agreed starting pointn nor a fixed or agreed ending point. The context is wrong as tchrist proposes it: it is not only to do with the direction of travel but the relative location - recede is in its own antonymic position about the transfer of power from one body to another, not the relative spatial location of one body to another - recede means to depart from an existing known poision. Recede is not the antonym of approach.

The nearest antonym appears to be "withdraw" as it does not imply, in the first instance, a connection, but it implies a termination of influence, but as we have seen above, the antonym of approach does not imply permanence or a totality of arrival.

The nearest antonym then seems to be one which can imply moving from near to far but remaining under the influence of the perceiving origio, therfore the verb "to pass" as in "to pass by", "to fly past", "half past one", "the ship approached but then passed on by", "he was approaching death and then passed away".

If the antonym of "approach" is "pass" this makes sense in terms of the noun also. One can create an approach to something, but if one creates a pass, then that implies that an approach is not made.

This makes sense in different conceptual aspects - referring to emotional states, time, actual spatial location, and metaphors for concluding a thought or conversation we can see in the example "they were approaching the climax" the direct substitution of the antonym (which is an aspect of the antonym in that it can directly replace the word in the same grammatical form) does work: "they were passing the climax" which means they passed the point of no return and therefore does in fact meet both criteria of stopping the sense of approaching and with the capability of becoming far, but not being out of site, as approaching from a place observed to be near but not having joined.

Again we can see this works in the sense of the abstract conceptual domain of business in "he made the approach" of which the antonym is "he passed up the offer".

Comment: Recede has a sense of "to yield", of giving up something previously held, to withdraw from a position held. The problem with approach is that it means not being part of something, only coming near. For that reason recede is not the antonym of approach - etymologically they come from sources that imply different kinds of conceptual metaphor. If something stops approaching, then to some extent it is better referred to as "waning" or "fading" - any word that means giving up a held position, or leaving a particular place or state misses the point that "approaching" means only coming near.

Answer (score -4):

Drifting is the world which is best suited in this scenario. Approaching means  coming near to a an object or a person whereas drifting means going away from a source.So 'drifting' represents an appropriate antonym of 'approaching'.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some [explanation and context](//english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with [citations](//english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Answers that don't include explanations may be [removed](//english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Drifting means a rather random movement. Drifting away works in some contexts, but a train doesn't drift away from the station.

Comment: Approaching means coming towards  a person or an object and 'drifting away' means going away from the source. Here random movement or movement in a particular direction is immaterial.